# Does the French word for Friday, "vendredi", come from the Latin "Veneris" or the old Norse "Vanadis"?

Tags: etymology, latin, french, old-norse, old-french

When looking up the etymology of the French *vendredi* online, I can only find the suggestion that it comes from the Latin *Veneris* (Venus).

However, the English, German, Dutch, Norwegian, Danish and Swedish words for Friday all come from either *Frigg* or *Freyja* (which both likely originate from the same Germanic/Norse goddess), who is also referred to as *Vanadis*.

Considering the similarity between *vendre* in *vendredi* and *Vanadis*, and taking into account that many neighbouring languages derive their words for Friday from the same god, is it reasonable to suspect that the French word *vendredi* also comes from Freyja?

Comment: All other French words for weekdays come from Latin: Lunedi, Mardi, Mercredi, Jeudi, Samedi - why would the word for Friday come from a different origin?

Comment: The /d/ appearing in the French word seems to be the source of your hypothesis. It's worth noting this is the standard development resulting from /n/ and /r/ brought in contact by the loss of an intervening vowel: lat. generum -> fr. gendre; lat. cinerem -> fr. cendre; lat. minor, fr. moindre

Comment: The Luis Henrique's comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Very unlikely!

While the phonetic similarities *are* real, the old Norse name of the weekday etymologically goes back to *Frig's day*, and not *Freyja's day*.

The actual form of the Norse word is somewhat blurred by a possible early loan from Old Saxon (or some other such west Germanic language) into the attested Norse **frjádagʀ**. This form is very likely from an unattested old Norse **frīadagʀ* before the diphthong, indicated by **-īa-* here, changed to **-já-**. The same change is attested and exemplified in **Kíarr** > **Kjárr** 'Caesar', and the source form of the initial **frīa-* is backed up by Faroese reflex **fríggjadagur**, which (due to a Faroese sound change called *skerping*) must come from an older **-īa-* sequence.

This was probably a loan from an unattested Saxon form such as **frīadag* (backed up by cognates in Old High German **frīatag** and Old English **frīġedæġ**), etymologically sourced from proto-Germanic **frijjōzdagaz* 'Frig's day'. The Norse form would have been reflected as **friggjudagʀ*, which we cannot find anywhere.

The etymology of the word as 'Freyja's day' is untenable because the only time **freyjudagʀ** appears is in Old Icelandic, attested only in certain authors and *later* than **frjádagʀ** — and can probably be discarded as a poetic or stylistic innovation.

Beyond this, **Vanadís** as the name of Freyja is only a very ritualised poetic convention (a kenning for skaldic poetry, to be specific) and is not a spoken form. It is quite unlikely that this byname would be used to refer to Freyja when her actual name itself was much, much more commonly used.

Comment: Great and detailed answer! A bit hard to read though (so many clauses and parentheses), maybe it's possible to structure the answer a bit?

Comment: @Betohaku, oh yes definitely. I'll rewrite it a bit on Sunday.

Comment: @Betohaku hopefully it's a bit more legible now.

Answer (score 9):

The etymology of vendredi is completely straightforward. It is from “Veneris dies” (the day of Venus), well attested in Roman texts as the name for one of the seven days of the “planetary” week.